# Prove $\vert \mathbb{E}[X]^2- \mathbb{E}[Y]^2 \vert \leq (\mathbb{E}[X] - \mathbb{E}[Y])^2$

Tags: probability

Let $X,Y$ denote real random variables both bounded by 1. I want to prove that
$$
\vert (\mathbb{E}[X])^2- (\mathbb{E}[Y])^2 \vert \leq (\mathbb{E}[X] - \mathbb{E}[Y])^2.
$$
I have tried applying Jensen's inequality (as $\vert \cdot \vert$ and  $\cdot ^2$ are convex functions) but with no luck. Can someone help me?

Comment: Let Var(X) and Var(Y) = 2 and both have mean 0. Therefore EX^2 =1 and EY^2 =2. LHS = 1 and RHS =0. Doesn't hold

Comment: I mean Var(X) =1 and Var(Y) =2 in the above comment

Comment: @rostader I think you may be misreading where the exponent is on the left-hand side?

Comment: I have added parenthesis to make it clearer

Comment: Try $\mathbb{E}[X] = 1/2$ and $\mathbb{E}[Y] = 1/4$.  Your inequality is then $3/16 \leq 1/16$, which is wrong.  In fact, if both the expectations have the same sign, the inequality is backwards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $a = \mathbb E[X]$ and $b = \mathbb E[Y]$; you want to prove that $|a^2 - b^2| \leq (a - b)^2$. The expected value formulation is sort of a distraction here.

With this formulation, you can fairly easily find a counterexample to show that the statement is false. **HINT**: WOLOG, suppose $a > b$. Then the left side is $(a + b)(a-b)$ and the right side is $(a-b)(a-b)$.